Error: AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
I am making a digital assistant, (A non-malware BonziBuddy clone, if you will), and this error occurs when I try to display an image in the "character" window, I get this error. Here is my code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Mon/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    pyimage1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=PIL.Image.open("assets/1.png"))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/runner/Mon/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 102, in __init__
    image = _get_image_from_kw(kw)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/runner/Mon/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 59, in _get_image_from_kw
    return Image.open(source)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/runner/Mon/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3442, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
             ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x7e67e762ea20>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Mon/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 132, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'

Here is the error:
File "/home/runner/Mon/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 102, in __init__
    image = _get_image_from_kw(kw)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/runner/Mon/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 59, in _get_image_from_kw
    return Image.open(source)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/runner/Mon/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3442, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
             ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x7e67e762ea20>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Mon/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 132, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'


The result of PIL.Image.open() is certainly not a file, you shouldn't be passing it as the file= parameter to ImageTk.PhotoImage().
